# How to get a static positioned element to span the screen

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an element that I need so span across the whole screen.

It need to be static positioned because it needs to be in the flow of elements but setting the width to 100% doesn't cover the screen.

I could make it absolute positioned and then set the `left` and `right` properties to `0` and it would cover the screen, but then the element would be taken out of the flow of DOM elements and mess it up.

How can I make a static positioned element span the whole screen?

Here is a supporting jsfiddle: http://jsbin.com/uwepij

Comment: Is it possible to remove the margin from your body? or is that needed?
`body {margin: 0 !important;}`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the body had a margin by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont need the margin in body you can use:
Body{margin:0;}

Answer (score 2):

Elements that are `position: static` don't, by default, span more than the width of their parent element.

In the case you're seeing, the body element has a margin of `8px` on it, so all of the non-absolute positioned elements are limited to that space.

If, however, you *know* how much extra space you want the element to span, you can set a padding and negative margin on the element like so:

```
padding: 0 10px;
margin: 0 -10px;
```

See the above as an update to your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/amuxev

Comment: Your solution works as well, but the top one is easier. I gave you an upvote